# Why is There a Repeating Structure of the Distance Matrices of the Graphs of Regular Polytopes?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, finite-groups, polyhedra

In some work I've done recently. I have been analyzing the distance matrix of the regular polyhedra in multiple dimensions and have found some curious results.

Starting in 2 dimensions, I have found that if you label the vertices cyclically, where the labeling of the vertices corresponds to the row and column of the distance matrix, the distance matrix will always be a symmetric circulant matrix of size $n\times n$, where n is the number of vertices for the polygon. Of course this is a well-known property of cyclic graphs in general which all the polygons are.

In 3 dimensions, there are only 5 regular polyhedra. However, they all display the same interesting properties. I have found that for all there exists a labeling of their vertices that gives a block bi-symmetric matrix where each block is a symmetric circulant matrix of the same size. In general, this labeling is not as trivial as in the 2 dimensional case and I have found no better way of finding it other than by guess and check. This becomes increasingly difficult for large polyhedra as the number of possible labelings grows as $n!$ where n is the number of vertices of the polyhedra. The following is the structure of the distance matrix for each of the 5 regular polyhedra.

Tetrahedron: $4\times 4$ symetric circulant matrix

Octohedron: $6\times 6$ symetric circulant matrix

Cube: $2\times 2$ block bi-symetric matrix of $4\times 4$ symetric circulant matricies

Icosahedron: $2\times 2$ block bi-symetric matrix of $6\times 6$ symetric circulant matricies

Dodecahedron: $4\times 4$ block bi-symetric matrix of $5\times 5$ symetric circulant matricies

In 4 dimensions the same pattern arises for the polytope I have checked.

Pentachron: $5\times 5$ symetric circulant matrix

Hexadecachron: $8\times 8$ symetric circulant matrix

Tesseract: $4\times 4$ block bi-symmetric matrix (which happens to also be block symmetric circulant) of $4\times 4$ symmetric circulant matrices

This is as many as I have checked. The structure is very interesting because bi-symmetric matrices have many unique properties that can be exploited, and symmetric circulant matrices do as well. I have multiple questions about this phenomenon. Does this pattern persist for all regular polytopes in any dimension? What about the regular polytopes give rise to this distance matrix structure? Is there any way to predict what the structure will be from topological invariants of the graphs? Are there other graphs that satisfy this unique property?

I haven't been able to find any papers written on this phenomenon so any help trying to better understand what is going on would be very helpful.

Comment: Your work may be easier in higher dimensions since for $n \ge 5$ the only regular polytopes are the simplex, the $n$-cube, and its dual, the cross polytope. In dimension $4$ there are three others. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope

Comment: @EthanBolker while there are less polytopes in the higher dimensions the number of vericies grows exponentially, and hence the search space for labelings that produce these unique distance matricies grows very quickly.

Comment: Does it matter so much if the polyhedron is regular? Have you tried making distance matrices for say [Archimedean solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid) or [Johnson solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid)? Or did you somehow use the symmetry groups of regular polyhedra when composing the numbering of vertices?

Comment: @kabenyuk I don't know if the fact that there regular polyhedra matters in relation to this distinct distance matrix structer. It is just that these are the only ones I have checked. I did not use an explicit algorithm that uses the symetry of the polyhedra but in my guess and check aproach starting at a configuration that is based on the symetries and structer of the network helps alot. I haven't checked more because it is a quite labor intensive task for the more complicated polyhedra.

Comment: @AidanR.S.,Thank you for your detailed response. Still I think it would be quite interesting to explore as many different polyhedra as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to take out my d20 and stare at it for a bit for this one. I don't have a rigorous proof, but I'm convinced that in any dimension, by definition of what a 'regular' polytope is... you can pick any reference point arbitrarily, since they're all symmetric. You can then define the 'depth' of every other vertex as the minimum number of edges you would have to traverse to move there.

If the distance from the reference point to any two points at the same depth were different, that would have to break the defining symmetry of the object. Any two paths from the reference to a point at a given depth should be identical up to a rotation and or a reflection that preserves distance.

If your data disconfirms this, please let me know! But I suspect that each row in your matrices, no matter how you label the vertices, should have a number of distinct nonzero values equal to the max depth of the vertices as a graph/tree (with arbitrary starting point having value zero) and multiplicities equal to the number of vertices at a given depth. For the cube, $1,3,3,1$, for the icosahedron $1,5,5,1$, for the dodecahedron $1,3,6,6,3,1$, etc.

Hopefully this at least helps explain why the matrices must always be circulant, and why a permutation of the rows and columns might always permit a symmetric or block bisymmetric arrangement.

Comment: I believe your correct about the shortest paths to a certain depth can be transformed into one another via symetries of the polytope. I was wondering if you could be a bit more explicit about how this gives rise to block bi-syemtric structers of symetric circulent matricies? That part is not really connecting for me.

Comment: I originally thought that the path symmetry (the symmetry in general under all possible rotations) meant that every circulant arrangement of those values, in a valid order, is a valid labeling... And that there is always a valid ordering of the first row that creates block symmetry when repeated circulantly... But when I try to reason out exactly why, neither of those propositions are trivial. I'll try to come back to it after the holiday :)

Comment: I think every permutation of rows and columns is a valid relabeling, as long as you always apply the same permutation to rows and columns at the same time (switch any two rows and switch the same two columns, and the matrix is still valid). It's like trying to solve a rubix cube

Comment: The blocks probably represent cycles of permutations that act on a subset of vertices cyclically while maintaining the circulant structure of all of the other vertices. In the dodecahedron, it's the five vertices on each of four faces that permit such permutations (2 pairs of opposite faces)